# Ruby on Rails on Ubuntu - Multiple Errors

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ubuntu

I installed Ubuntu 10.04 then upgraded it to 12.04.  From there I followed this tutorial on setting up RoR:
http://ryanbigg.com/2010/12/ubuntu-ruby-rvm-rails-and-you/

However, I'm here because I've spent more than 12 hours fighting with different error messages and want to shoot someone.

Error 1:

```
greg2@greg-desktop:~/bballApp$ ruby -v
ruby 1.8.7 (2011-06-30 patchlevel 352) [i686-linux]
greg2@greg-desktop:~/bballApp$ rails -v
/home/greg2/bballApp/Gemfile:3:in `evaluate': undefined method `ruby' for #<Bundler::Dsl:0xb7607a18> (NoMethodError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:136:in `definition'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:124:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/setup.rb:7
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/greg2/bballApp/config/boot.rb:6
from script/rails:5:in `require'
from script/rails:5
```

Error 2:

```
greg2@greg-desktop:~/bballApp$ bundle install
Your Ruby version is 1.8.7, but your Gemfile specified 1.9.3
```

So, google told me to look at my .zshrc file and add:

```
[[ -s "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm" ]] && . "$HOME/.rvm/scripts/rvm"
```

Which I then did.

Returned and got the same errors.  So I tried:

```
greg2@greg-desktop:~/bballApp$ rvm list
rvm rubies
   ruby-1.9.3-p194 [ i686 ]
=* ruby-1.9.3-p362 [ i686 ]
```

I'm developing this with a friend who's running this on a MAC.

Here's my gem list:

```
greg2@greg-desktop:~/bballApp$ gem list
```

*** LOCAL GEMS ***

```
actionmailer (3.2.11, 3.2.9.rc3)
actionpack (3.2.11, 3.2.9.rc3)
activemodel (3.2.11, 3.2.9.rc3)
activerecord (3.2.11, 3.2.9.rc3)
activeresource (3.2.11, 3.2.9.rc3)
activesupport (3.2.11, 3.2.9.rc3)
addressable (2.3.2)
arel (3.0.2)
bcrypt-ruby (3.0.1)
bourne (1.1.2)
builder (3.0.4)
bundler (1.3.0.pre.5, 1.2.3, 1.1.5)
coffee-rails (3.2.2)
coffee-script (2.2.0)
coffee-script-source (1.4.0)
erubis (2.7.0)
execjs (1.4.0)
hike (1.2.1)
i18n (0.6.1)
journey (1.0.4)
jquery-rails (2.1.4)
json (1.7.6)
mail (2.4.4)
metaclass (0.0.1)
mime-types (1.19)
mocha (0.10.5)
multi_json (1.5.0)
 polyglot (0.3.3)
rack (1.4.4, 1.4.3)
rack-cache (1.2)
rack-ssl (1.3.2)
rack-test (0.6.2)
rails (3.2.11, 3.2.9.rc3)
railties (3.2.11, 3.2.9.rc3)
rake (10.0.3)
rdoc (3.12)
sass (3.2.5)
sass-rails (3.2.6)
sprockets (2.2.2)
sqlite3 (1.3.7)
thor (0.16.0)
tilt (1.3.3)
treetop (1.4.12)
tzinfo (0.3.35)
uglifier (1.3.0)
```

Here's what happens when I run rails s.

```
greg2@greg-desktop:~/bballApp$ rails s
/home/greg2/bballApp/Gemfile:3:in `evaluate': undefined method `ruby' for #<Bundler::Dsl:0xb765fa10> (NoMethodError)
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/definition.rb:17:in `build'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:136:in `definition'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:124:in `load'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler.rb:107:in `setup'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/bundler/setup.rb:7
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `gem_original_require'
from /usr/lib/ruby/vendor_ruby/1.8/rubygems/custom_require.rb:36:in `require'
from /home/greg2/bballApp/config/boot.rb:6
from script/rails:5:in `require'
from script/rails:5
```

- **I'm exhausted, out of ideas, and if you're in WI will drive and buy you a beer for getting this to run. Thank you for your help.;**

Comment: Have you done this?: `rvm --default use 1.9.3-p362`

Comment: What's in your `Gemfile`? Am surprised to see `ruby version` being specified in the `Gemfile`!

Comment: Removing it from my gem file fixed it.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As @Prakash Murty said you seem to define the ruby version in your Gemfile. This line is used for Heroku to specify your ruby version.

If you want to use it you need to use bundler version 1.2.0.

More informations here: https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/ruby-versions

However if you don't use heroku to host your app, I suggest you to remove this line of your Gemfile.

I hope this help.